# Qooxdoo REST JSON request problem - unexpected token and then timeout

Tags: django, json, rest, qooxdoo

I am learning Qooxdoo framework and I am trying to make it work with a small Django web service. Django webservice just returns JSON data like this:

```
{ "name": "Football", "description": "The most popular sport." }
```

Then I use the following code to query that url:

```
var req = new qx.io.remote.Request(url, "GET", "application/json");
req.toggleCrossDomain();

req.addListener("completed", function(e) {
                 alert(e.getContent());
                    });
req.send();
```

Unfortunately when I execute the code I get unexpected token error and then request timeouts.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Native.js:91013011 qx.io.remote.RequestQueue[246]: Timeout: transport 248
Native.js:91013011 qx.io.remote.RequestQueue[246]: 5036ms > 5000ms
Native.js:91013013 qx.io.remote.Exchange[248]: Timeout: implementation 249
```

JSLint reports that this is a valid JSON, so I wonder why Qooxdoo doesn't parse it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is probably with this line:

req.toggleCrossDomain();

crossDomain is false by default, so toggleCrossDomain sets it to true. This forces qx.io.remote.Request to use the script transport, which doesn't work like a regular XMLHttpRequest: The request needs to contain an id, while the server's response must use the same id and wrap the actual response in a call to qx.io.remote.transport.Script._requestFinished(). This is explained in greater detail in the documentation for the qx.io.remote package:

http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.io.remote

Answer (score 0):

Your request is timing out. Is the URL right? Are there firewall issues connecting to it? Basically, your code is not receiving the JSON you expect, but is instead receiving a timeout error.

Comment: Through logs I can see that server is getting the request correctly, so URL is right and request reaches it.

Comment: OK. It's timing out giving the response then. Your error is because the error message (which you have actually posted above) is being parsed as JSON, which it isn't.

Comment: I've increased timeout to 1000000ms, JavaScript console shows that it first throws that unexpected token error and only then (much later) gets a timeout.